# Bind an object which has a property of type List<> to a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, webforms

I've created two classes in business layer.

the first one is called Users with id (int), pass (string) and privileges (Privilege) properties and the second one is called Privilege and has id (int) and privilegeName (string) properties.

I've a method that returns all the users, and I use a repeater (actually I bind it to a DataList to auto create the ItemTemplate for me and then use a repeater) and it works and displays all the properties well except for my List property. it generates instead something like this System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication2.Public.BLL.Users]

I want to display it in a friendly way like "User Privileges : Privi1, Privi2" but still I want to keep the layers of my application clean and structured, for example I won't store them in a database in the same table and just store them as a text and append it.

I hope to find a simple and good solution...Thanks in advance guys =)

PS : I don't want to display the object Privilege, I want to display privilege.privilegeName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using repeaters, there are two approaches, one is the one suggested by Bugai13: to have a custom property that displays it. This is fine for certain types of nested data.

Your other option is to just have a repeater inside a repeater, and bind it appropriately (to what would be a list  assigned to your main data object, depending on how you O/R Mapper works).

You can have the code for the custom display property not in the data model, but in your presentation layer somewhere (depending on your framework/design), so it's not a "bad" thing to do that. It's up to you, with whatever "feels" best.

Comment: when I declared the property as a string instead of a List<> I need to split and and join it every time I store in the db or retrieve from the bd, that's why I thought a List<> property would be better. I'm not very experienced but I was hoping to build a good application architecture wise...but if you have a different opinion please share it

and btw how do I bind the privilege.privilegeName to the nested repeater ? or should I use a whole new method that loads the privileges and bind it to the nested repeater ?

Comment: @IKashef: I'm assuming you have an object model with the `User` class having a `List<...> Privs` property. Your data model can be something like that; i.e. correct and formally structured as a tree. When it comes to viewing it, you can use a repeater in a repeater (google for how to do it if you don't know, it's easy enough), and display it appropriately. If you aren't already, I'd highly recommend an O/R Mapper for your Data access layer/model, I personally use LLBLGen.

Comment: Thanks for the information +1 ...I have some idea on how to use the nested repeater and I'll google it for an accurate example but what I meant to say, what will be the data source for the second repeater ? should I declare a method in the the Privilege class to retrieve privileges or I can bind it to a property ?....can I know what is this O/R Mapper or what will it do for me ? I'm already researching about it, but I hope I'd get a one liner introduction about it!

Comment: You simply set the datasource of the second repeater to your List<Pri..>. But you will have to use the ItemDataBound event of first repeater, where you will find the second repeater and databind it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create property at your Bussiness object, and bind it:

```
public string PrivilegiesString
{
   get
   {
     var sb = new StringBuilder("User Privileges : ");
     foreach(var item in privileges)
     {
       sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ",item.privilegeName);
     }

     return sb.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it's a good approach -architecture wise- ? I mean isn't better to just handle this in the presentation layer, like instead of Text = '<#% Eval("privileges")%>' it would be ' string.Join(", ", (<#%Eval("privileges.privilegName")%>'....I'm totally not sure of this code, but I hope you understood what I was trying to say!

Comment: If you don't want to add this property to Bussiness layer you can create some presentation item for page and map privilegies to string property of presentation object.

Comment: Also you can't put some logic inside of 'Eval', because Eval just get a property value by name using reflection.

Comment: @Bugai13- well, seems like Eval can't help in this situation as I don't to display the object itself, I want to display it's property. so please could you give me an advice on how to achieve that considering that I'm not just concerned about getting things done, I want to build a strong architecture for this application.

Comment: If the privileges are simply for display purpose and if you don't want to edit them then this approach or something similar should work but again Eval will not help in any case.

Comment: @gbs- actually there is a many to many relationship between privileges and users table. I don't edit them frequently but the option will be available, also It's very possible to add or remove privileges and sometimes it will be displayed in a LinkButton instead of a Label and pass it's ID as it's command argument.